# What valve would be the best for a model rocket with a hybrid engine?

Tags: jet-engine, rocket

I am planning on building a model rocket with a hybrid engine. I am trying to find the best valve that could be used for the MOV, main oxygen valve. I plan to use gaseous oxygen and would like the valve to be electrically actuated, and have the ability to throttle. Does anybody have any recommendations for a good valve to use? Thank you.

Comment: I think this question is better suited on [space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Technically, this cannot be a "model rocket" engine -- by legal definition, a model rocket uses only commercially made engines certified by either NAR or Tripoli Rocket Association (names may have changed in 20+ years I've been away from model rocketry).  This would be an "amateur rocket engine" and must meet a whole different set of legal requirements and insurance conditions.  Hint: you probably can't afford the insurance you should have to fly this anywhere other than Black Rock Desert or similar places.

Comment: @Zeissikon Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of factors.
Most valves with the specs you need will work really, but you'll have to carefully determine your specs. There's not really a single answer.

What kind of thrust are you designing your engine for? This (amongst other things) will determine your minimum needed flow rate, and will determine the pressures this valve will need to be able to cope with. These things will be the most important valve specs you'll be considering.

I don't know where exactly your valve will be in your engine, but make sure it can withstand the heat its exposed to.

On the flipside, knowing you'll be using GOX, you'll probably just use the pressure from your oxygen tank to power your engine. As the oxygen will be expanding, the MOV might tend to freeze up and lock itself in place. Beware of that as well when choosing a valve.

Not all valves will be able to safely operate in a pure oxygen environment. However, as we're talking model rockets here (the operating time of your engine is quite short I suppose) it'd surprise me if that would turn out to be an issue.

To end with, although maybe not directly related to your question about the valve, make sure you understand hybrid engine throttling. [It can get more complicated than you might anticipate.](http://mae-nas.eng.usu.edu/MAE_6530_Web/New_Course/Section3/section2.2.pdf)

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you for the help!